# How to store & get own secret key in Java 8 PKCS12 keystore

Tags: java, keystore, pkcs#12

I am trying to store my own secret key in PKCS12 keystore. I tried by using below code:

```
char[] passArray = "password".toCharArray();// this is key store pass

String key  = "test123"; // this is my own secret key

// Loading a Keystore
KeyStore p12KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
p12KeyStore.load(new FileInputStream("testKeyStore.p12"), passArray);
```

Storing my own secret key like as shown below:

```
byte [] byteKey = key.getBytes();

SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, "DSA");

KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secret = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(keySpec);

KeyStore.ProtectionParameter password = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(passArray);

p12KeyStore.setEntry("secret-key", secret, password);
```

but i am not sure whether storing the my own secret key as per best practice or not. and also when trying to get my own key from keystore as it is not getting like as my original secret key.

```
Key eKey = p12KeyStore.getKey("secret-key", passArray);
```

Can anyone please help me on this to store & get my own secret in PKCS12 keystore?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the code you have above worked? Because `DSA` is a asymmetric algorithm, not a symmetric algorithm. If you are sure it is a secret key, it has to be `AES` or `DES` or `DESede` (Triple DES). Your above code should have failed.

And answers to your questions:

- Just like databases stores data, keys (secret keys and key pairs) and certificates are meant to be stored in a keystore, that's where they should residing in your application. You should be referring/retrieving them from the keystore.
- And from what you said in one of the statements, that the key is different from what you had originally when you stored and then retrieved, judging by this, I think the key you have is a `Triple DES` or a `DES` key. DES/TripleDES uses parity bits, and the parity bits are corrected by the Java API `SecretKeySpec`. This causes the key to look different from the original, but it is actually the same. You can read more about the parity bits [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit).

And as a best practice you shouldn't be storing the secret keys in a `PKCS12` Keystore. The internet standard defines that the `PKCS12` keystore should contain only one `KeyPair` entry associated with its certificate chain. Even though it can contain more than one entry, it is ideal to have only one entry, with the `key password` same as the `keystore password`. They can store secret keys too, but it is best if you store them in a `JCEKS` keystore format.

Comment: This is not correct. The [RFC-7292](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292) section 4.2 defines 6 different SafeBag types. Type 5 is the SecretBag. (_Each of the user's miscellaneous personal secrets is contained in an instance of SecretBag, which holds an object identifier-dependent value.  Note that a SecretBag contains only one secret._)